# How do I add a dollar sign to the front of the column?

Tags: sql-server

Code:
use db1
go

SELECT format(msalary, 'N0') AS msalary, format(mbonus, 'N0')
FROM HAFHMORE.manager

How do I add a $ sign in front of the results from the query? Thank you!

Comment: Formatting should be done in the presentation layer, not the RDBMS. Define the format you want the value in the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CONCAT for that:

```
SELECT  CONCAT('$',format(msalary, 'N0')) AS msalary,  CONCAT('$',format(mbonus, 'N0')) FROM HAFHMORE.manager
```

Answer (score 2):

To format as a currency use 'C' as the 2nd argument of the `FORMAT` function:

```
SELECT format(msalary, , 'C', 'en-us') AS msalary, format(mbonus, , 'C', 'en-us') FROM HAFHMORE.manager
```